# How to solve for $y'(x) = y(x+1)$?

Tags: analysis, reference-request, delay-differential-equations

I'm interested in equations like $y'(x) = y(x+1)$. Note that the argument of the function $y$ on the right hand side of that last equation is $x+1$. The right hand side does not contain a multiplication. We have a function $y$ that takes an argument $x$ which is written as $y(x)$. So the derivative of the solution is equal to the value of the solution "a little bit to the right". I do have an application for this, in case somebody would ask, but I'm interested most of all in the general theory instead of the specific instance (so no XY-problem; thanks Xander H.!).

I can't find the correct name for this kind of equations. Can somebody provide me a pointer?

Comment: This is a functional equation.

Comment: This is a delay differential equation.

Comment: (where the delay is negative) . Solutions include linear combinations of $y = e^{rx}$ where $r$ is a branch of $-W(-1)$ where $W$ is the Lambert W function.  These $r$ are all complex.

Comment: Thus real solutions include $y = e^{a x} \cos(b x)$ and $y = e^{ax} \sin(b x)$ with $a \approx 0.3181315052$ and $b \approx 1.33723570$, these being the real and imaginary parts of the "$-1$" branch.

Comment: You say that you have an application for this, which gives the impression that this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Can you please edit your question to include this context?  As RobertIsrael suggests, there are ways of obtaining solutions in terms of Lambert's $W$, but it would be helpful to know, for example, if you are looking for an exact answer or a numerical approximation.